# capacity of a point.

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, geometric-measure-theory, potential-theory

I am trying to understand the concept of $(p,\mu)$-capacity, which in the book by Heinonen, Kilpelainen and Martio, the capacity of a compact set $K \subset \Omega$  is defined by:
$$cap_{p,\mu}(K,\Omega) = \inf_{u\in W(K,\Omega)} \int_{\Omega}{|\nabla u|^{p}}d\mu$$

Where, $W(K,\Omega)=\{u \in C_{0}^{\infty}(\Omega): u \geq 1\ on\ K\}$

The authors mention that throughout the whole book, $\Omega$ is an open subset of $R^{n}$ and $n \geq 2$.

I am trying to understand what is the capacity of a point. I know and I think it  is not hard to prove  that the capacity of a point is zero as long as $1<p \leq n$. However, I read in a paper that if $p>n$ the capacity of a point is always greater than zero.

Can somebody help me to understand why this happens?

I know that for $p>n=1$ any function in the Sobolev space $W^{1,p}((a,b))$ with (a,b) bounded is a.e equal to an abosolutely continuous function. However, I don't know how to use that to show that in the one dimensional case (or more general in $p>n$ case) the capacity of a point is positive.

Thank you

Comment: I think the idea is that if $p>n$ then $W^{1,p}$ embeds into $C^{0,\gamma}$ for some $0<\gamma<1$. So now you have a continuous function which is $\geq 1$ at one point, and therefore $>1/2$ on some nonempty open set, and also vanishes at the boundary. Then its gradient can't be "too small" or else it would fail to vanish at the boundary. It seems to me that this property requires some hypothesis on $\mu$, though.

Comment: Thanks, this helps me to understand it a little bit better.

Answer (score 2):

The point is that if $p>n$ then the Sobolev embedding $W^{1,p}_0\hookrightarrow C^{0,\gamma}$, with $\gamma=1-\frac{n}{p}$, is *continuous* (I am assuming $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure, otherwise for general measures both the embedding and the result you ask fail). Since trivially also $C^{0,\gamma}\hookrightarrow C^0$ is continuous, we have a continuous embedding $W^{1,p}_0\hookrightarrow C^0$. This means that, given $u\in C^\infty_0(\Omega)$, we have
$$ \|u\|_{C^0(\Omega)}=\|u\|_\infty\leq M \|u\|_{W^{1,p}_0(\Omega)}.
$$
By the  Poincaré inequality the $W^{1,p}$-norm on $W^{1,p}_0$ is equivalent to $\|\nabla u\|_{L^p(\Omega)}$, therefore we have
$$\|u\|_\infty\leq \tilde M \left(\int\limits_\Omega|\nabla u|^p\right)^{1/p}
$$
for any $u\in C^\infty_0(\Omega)$. In particular for any nonempty $K$ and $u\in W(K,\Omega)$ the left hand side is greater than 1, so that the infimum in the definition of capacity gives a positive number.

In dimension one actually the result holds for $p\geq 1$, and there's a simple argument to show it: call $c$ the point in $(a,b)$ which you want to compute the capacity of. Then given $u\in C^\infty_0(a,b)$
$$\int_a^b |u'|=\int_a^c|u'|+\int_c^b|u'|\geq \left|\int_a^c u'\right|+\left|\int_c^b u'\right|=|u(c)-u(a)|+|u(b)-u(c)|\geq 2.
$$